# can't launch crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm working on Visual Studio 2008 to develop a web application in asp.net.

if I add a crystal report file (.rpt) in my project, I see only hexadecimal code.

I obviously miss something.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Visual Studio you're using - not all versions come with Crystal Reports. e.g. I know that Express version doesn't... And you can't add manually Crystal Reports to Express version because I think it doesn't support plugins (that's why it's free).